# Problema al activar y actualizar cuenta de nuevo usuario a traves de url y consultas preparadas MySQL - php

Tags: php, mysql

Hola que tal? Resiban un cordial saludo de mi parte.

Quisiera que me ayuden a solucionar el error que presenta mi pequeño sistema de activación de cuenta de usuarios.
El proceso es algo largo, desde el formulario de registro, validación y limpieza de los inputs hasta el registro y activación de la cuenta.

Ya estuve realizando varias pruebas y la parte del proceso que presenta falla es la de activar la cuenta. Para ello, previamente el usuario se registra, y se le envía un correo con el enlace (url) de activación, el cual contiene los paraétros 'id, val, id_brand' que se utilizan dinámicamente en distintas partes del proceo.

La url es como esta:

url: http://localhost/activar.php?id=59&val=af5757a810dd0f6bf1da79e6e9456f65&id_brand=43

A partir de la url que abre el usuario, continúa el proceso de activación de cuenta. Al abrir el enlace (archivo /activar.php), se realizan la validación de los paámetros realizando consultas a la base de datos en MySQL y en específico a las tablas 'admins' y 'brands'.

Cabe mencionar que hastá este punto, el proceso previo, el de registro de la cuenta ha terminado con los resultados esperados. El problema comienza a partir de que el usuario abre el enlace de activación. Simplemente, no se actualiza la tabla después de terminar el proceso de activación de cuenta, por lo tanto, la cuenta del nuevo usuario no se activa.

Parece que el error se encuentra en la función activarUsuario(). Pero bueno, les comparto el código, esperando que sea de su interés el analizarlo y brindarme su apoyo con la solución o posible solución a este error. Gracias!

function activarUsuario(); Encargada de activar la cuenta.

```
<?php
//Archivo funcs/funcs.php

function activarUsuario($id_brand, $id_tipo, $perfil, $id){
    
global $mysqli;   

    $sql = "UPDATE admins SET activacion = 1, id_brand = ?, id_tipo = ?, role = ? WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

    if ($stmt = $stmt->error) {
        die('Error en la preparación de la consulta: ' . $mysqli->error);
    }    
    $stmt->bind_param('iisi', $id_brand, $id_tipo, $perfil, $id);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    if ($result = $stmt->error) {
        die('Error al ejecutar la consulta: ' . $stmt->error);
    }
    return $result;
}
?>
```

**Contenido de las tablas.**

```
// Tabla admins
id  nombre       activacion            token                            

59   Nombre          0         af5757a810dd0f6bf1da79e6e9456f65
```

El $mensaje final de activación depende del token y de si el valor de activación es igual a 1, 2 o 3 ?

**Tabla brands.**

La función obtenerTipoAdmin() determina el número de columna en la que se encuentra registrado el id del usuario dentro de la tabla brands  y dependiendo la columna es el $perfil que se le asigna (Administrador o Proveedor)

```
id  nombre  admin_id    admin_id_2  admin_id_3  activa  representante   
42   mrca 1     55          56          NULL      1         0 
43   Marca      57          NULL        NULL      1         0   // id 43, mismo que el de la url
42   mrca 3     35          26           20       1         0
```

**Archivo '/activar.php'**

Verifica que los parámetros de la url no estén vacíos y los asigna a las varibales `$id`, `$id_brand` y `$token`.

En seguida, verifica el tipo de usuario con la variable `$id_tipo` la cual llama a la función `obtenerTipoAdmin($id_brand, $id);` Si `$id_tipo = 2;` se le asigna el valor de "Administrador" a la variable `$perfil`, pero si `$id_tipo = 3;`, el valor de `$perfil`es "Proveedor".

Finalmente se llama a la función `validaIdToken($token, $id_brand, $id_tipo, $perfil, $id);` y guardamos el resultado en la variable `$mensaje` para imrpimir un mensaje de activación al usuario.

```
<?php
require 'funcs/conexion.php'; // Conexion a la base de datos
require 'funciones/funcs.php';

$mensaje = ""; // Inicializar el mensaje

if (isset($_GET["id"]) && isset($_GET['val']) && isset($_GET['id_brand'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $token = $_GET['val'];
    $id_brand = $_GET['id_brand'];       
    $id_tipo = obtenerTipoAdmin($id_brand, $id); // Retorna 1 o 2 o 3
    
    if($id_tipo == 2) {
        $perfil = "Administrador";       
    } elseif ($id_tipo == 3) {        
        $perfil = "Proveedor";        
    } 
    $mensaje = validaIdToken($token, $id_brand, $id_tipo, $perfil, $id);
}     
?>
```

El mensaje se imprime en un div...

```
<html>
<body>
<div><?php echo $mensaje;?></div>
<div><a href="index.php">Ir a inicio</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Funciones involucradas en el proceso**

**obtenerTipoAdmin($id_brand, $id);**.
Función que retorna el número de columna en la que se encuentra el 'id' del usuario

```
<?php
//Archivo funciones/funcs.php 

function obtenerTipoAdmin($id_brand, $id) {
    global $mysqli;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM brands WHERE id = ? AND (admin_id = ? OR admin_id_2 = ? OR admin_id_3 = ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("iiii", $id_brand, $id, $id, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();

    return ($num === 1) ? 2 : 3; // Dependiendo del valor es el perfil de usuario "Administrador" o "Proveedor".
}
?>
```

**validaIdToken($token, $id_brand, $id_tipo, $perfil, $id);**

Consulta a la base de datos para confirmar si existe un registro en la tabla 'admins' con las variables $id, $token y si lo hay verificar el estatus de activación activa = 1, inactiva = 0.
Dependiendo del resultado, se imprime un mensaje avisándole al usuario del estatus de su cuenta.

```
<php
//Archivo funciones/funcs.php 

function validaIdToken($token, $id_brand, $id_tipo, $perfil, $id){
        global $mysqli;
        
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT activacion FROM admins WHERE token = ? AND id = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param("si", $token, $id);
        
        if(!stmt){
            die('Error en la preparación de la consulta: ' . $mysqli->error);
        }
        
        $stmt->execute();
        
        if(!stmt){
            die('Error en la Ejecución de la consulta: ' . $mysqli->error);
        }
        
        $stmt->store_result();
        
        
        $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    
        if($rows > 0) {
            $stmt->bind_result($activacion);
            $stmt->fetch();
            
            if($activacion == 1){
                $msg = "La cuenta ya se activo anteriormente.";
                } else {
                // Activamos la cuenta
                    activarUsuario($id_brand, $id_tipo, $perfil, $id);
                    $msg = 'Cuenta activada.';
                }
            } else {
            $msg = 'No existe el registro para activar.';
        }
        return $msg;
    }
?>
```

**function activarUsuario($id_brand, $id_tipo, $perfil, $id);**

Funcion encargargada de activar y actualizar la cuenta del usuario.
**Al parecer, aquí se presenta el error**

```
<?php
//Archivo funciones/funcs.php 

function activarUsuario($id_brand, $id_tipo, $perfil, $id)
{
    global $mysqli;

    $sql = "UPDATE admins SET activacion = 1, id_brand = ?, id_tipo = ?, role = ? WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

    if ($stmt = $stmt->error) {
        die('Error en la preparación de la consulta: ' . $mysqli->error);
    }
    
    $stmt->bind_param('iisi', $id_brand, $id_tipo, $perfil, $id);

    $result = $stmt->execute();

    if ($result = $stmt->error) {
        die('Error al ejecutar la consulta: ' . $stmt->error);
    }

    return $result;
}

?>
```

Intenté llamar a la function activarusuario(); fuera de la function validaIdToken(); dentro el archivo funcs.php pero estaría rompiendo el procósito del sistema de activación, incluso incluí llas funciones directamente en el archivo activar.php y no logro obtener el resultado esperado.

Si alguien requiere de analizar todo el proceso, desde el formulario, sin problema lo puedo compartir.

Espero que con la ayuda de ustedes pueda resolver este error

¡Saludos!